# Addition and Increment expression in [ ] - operator

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, iso

According to the standard are the following two expressions undefined behavior ?

```
int a = 1, b = 1; 
int c[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 

// Do the following expressions lead to Undefined Behavior ? 
c[a++]; // (1)  
c[a+b]; // (2)
```

Comment: `a` is not an array....

Comment: `a[a++];` is a compiler error

Comment: Did you mean `int c[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`?

Comment: Why would that be UB?

Comment: yup, sorry. I accidentally hit enter (?) which posted the question to early..

Comment: Do you get warnings on compile with -wAll enabled?  As is, this is not UB.

Comment: In order to make sense of the question you should explain *why* you think it could be UB.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Not getting a warning does not guarantee not having UB.

Comment: There is something wrong with the language if people think that such simple expressions could lead to UB.

Comment: @Slava IMHO, that's a bit of overstatement. Language is fine, sometimes we just miss the simplest of things, it happens. :)

Comment: @Olaf Question was edited on me.  As is now, yes no UB :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in their present form, they do not lead to undefined behaviour. There's no sequence point violation as you *might* have feared.

- In case of `c[a++];` the existing value of `a` is used in indexing, and `a` is incremented as the side effect (of the post-increment operator).
- `c[a+b];` none of the variable values are *altered* and `a+b` is a valid index of the array.

Comment: There is an example in the c++14 iso standard section `1.9.15` which lead to the confusion:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf 
But may I just misunderstand the section.

Comment: @SebNag That example is using the result of `v[i++]` to change `i`, which yields two unsequenced modifications of `i`. Btw, the C++14 standard would be N4141 (+- some typo / layout fixes maybe). N4296 is an intermediate draft.

Comment: @SebNag That is a different case, there, you're using the post increment on `i` __as well as__ assigning the RHS value back to `i`. Now, there's no sequence point between the execution of the side effect and assignment, where lies the problem.

Comment: @BaummitAugen off-topic, but just asking, the later version is draft??

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's the first C++17 draft afaik. Now that I think about it, I'm not sure if it contains *any* changes compared to C++14, but N4141 is the normal C++14 source afaik.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ahh.. that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may get an undefined behavior if the a or b or the sum of a and b is larger than the size of array:

```
int a = 1, b = 1; 
int c[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 

c[a++]; // (1)  a = 2
c[a+b]; // (2) a + b = 3

cout << c[a] << endl;   // 3
cout << c[a+b] << endl; // 4
cout << a << ", " << b << endl;
```

As you can see there is not UB because `c[a + b] = c[3]` which is an element of the array.